# Performance tools (Lighthouse) show very slow "Time to Interactive" on my Gatsby site. How can I improve it?

Tags: performance, gatsby

I'm looking for some help. My [website](https://playmirage.io/) is getting a very low time to interactive score (over 10 seconds).

It tells me I need to "Minimize main-thread work" and "Reduce JavaScript execution time".

Could you share some advice/tips on what I can do? How do you improve these metrics in your projects?

From googling, it seems like the main thing people do is code splitting, but Gatsby does that automatically already, right?

What else can be done?

Comment: Are you using Server Side Rendering?

Answer (score 4):

You have quite a good Lighthouse Score. Try to test your page in anonymous mode to disable extensions.

However, you can improve it.

- Load [bundle-analysys](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-bundle-analyzer) and check what is inside your bundles. Try to find duplicated scripts or scripts you are not using.
- Check importing strategy for the big scripts. If you are doing smth like `import * from 'lodash'` change it to `import {groupBy} from 'lodash'`
- Find possibility to use [lazy loading](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html). This is not done automatically. The best candidates for this would be other pages of your site.
- Then do revision for all scripts you have. Might be you can remove something that is not very important for you. Some people using jQuery for the querying page only.

Do general performance improvements:

- Reduce image sizes (on your landing page you have one quite big image for the 450KB).
- Reduce the number of fonts (you have 4 of them 547kb)
- Think about removing analytics or change it for something simpler

For tracking performance changes use [perfrunner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/perfrunner) or [lighthouse-ci](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse-ci)